# Enviar e Receber dados com popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Eu tenho uma lista na pagina pai da seguinte forma:

[image: Pagina Pai]

Quando eu clico em qualquer linha da tabela é aberto um popup, e estou fazendo isso da seguinte forma:

```
function abrePopUp(ID) { //aqui é o valor do ID que quero enviar
  var w, h, left, top;
  w = screen.width;
  h = screen.height;
  left = (w - 1300) / 2;
  settings = "width=1300, height=600, directories=no, location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no, resizable=no, left=" + left + ", top=200px";
  window.open("http://192.168.1.144/novoGrupo", "popup", settings);
};
```

O PopUp aberto é este:

[image: Pagina PopUp]

O que eu estou querendo é, pegar o valor do ID da linha que eu cliquei e colocar ele em uma variável na pagina do PopUp, como eu faço isso?

Comment: pode passar como parâmetro de query string, por exemplo  "/novoGrupo/?id=1" e recuperar isso na página

Answer (score 0):

O que poderia te ajudar seria trabalhar com `CustomEvents`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Com eles você tem a possibilidade de transitar os dados pelo seu app de forma nativa.